# How to save data to an xml file without duplicating data

Tags: c#, xml

My xml file looks like this:

```
<Osoby>

    <Osoba>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Imie>Jan</Imie>
    <Nazwisko>Kowalski</Nazwisko>
    <Wiek>23</Wiek>
    </Osoba>
    .
    .
    .
    <Osoba>
    <Id>500</Id>
    <Imie>Marek</Imie>
    <Nazwisko>Nowak</Nazwisko>
    <Wiek>37</Wiek>
    </Osoba>

</Osoby>
```

And and my procedure to write to the xml file,which generates 500 random people:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    button2.Visible = true;
    string[] Imie = { "Mariusz", "Mikołaj", "Przemek", "Krzysiek", "Patryk", "Janusz", "Lechu" };
    string[] Nazwisko = { "Kujawski", "Kowal", "Nowak", "Kowalski", "Dul", "Paleta", "Kawka" };
    Random losuj = new Random();

    XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("osoby.xml", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
    writer.WriteStartDocument(true);
    writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    writer.Indentation = 2;
    writer.WriteStartElement("Osoby");
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        createNode(i.ToString(), Imie[losuj.Next(0, 7)], Nazwisko[losuj.Next(0, 7)], losuj.Next(1, 50).ToString(), writer);
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteEndDocument();
    writer.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Utworzono plik XML ! ");
}
private void createNode(string pID, string pName, string pSurname, string pAge, XmlTextWriter writer)
{
    writer.WriteStartElement("Osoba");
    writer.WriteStartElement("Id");
    writer.WriteString(pID);
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteStartElement("Imie");
    writer.WriteString(pName);
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteStartElement("Nazwisko");
    writer.WriteString(pSurname);
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteStartElement("Wiek");
    writer.WriteString(pAge);
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteEndElement();
}
```

How can I save the data to an xml file without the people duplicate.

So for example: I do not want to have such twice people:

- Przemek Nowak 22 (years old)
- Przemek Nowak 22 (years old)

No matter the parameter 'id', which is unique because of the loop in the code.

Comment: You have arrays - you can use LINQ query, operator Distinct() will clear duplicates.

Comment: Keep the buffer List<string> that is written to XML file and there you go. LINQ willl help.

Answer (score 1):

Storing persons in a list for uniqueness testing has the disadvantage that the time complexity grows with `O(n^2)` (looping persons is linear and testing is linear, which combines to n^2). To get a linear complexity `O(n)` use a `HashSet<T>` (looping persons is linear, testing - automatically done while inserting - is constant).

To use a HashSet, create a Person class and override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is Person other) {
            return FirstName == other.FirstName && LastName == other.LastName;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked {
            return 17 * FirstName.GetHashCode() + LastName.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

For sake sake of simplicity I didn't check for nulls.

```
var persons = new HashSet<Person>();

while (persons.Count < 500) {
    var p = new Person { FirsName = ..., LastName = ... };
    persons.Add(p);
}
```

Note that HashSets automatically insert only unique persons, since they are formulated after the mathematical concept of sets that can contain each element only once, i.e. a set either contains an element or it does not contain it. So, no test like `if (!persons.Contains(p)) ...` is required.

---

You can create XML more easily with the classes from  namespace `System.Xml.Linq`. Create a document

```
var doc = new XDocument(new XElement("Osoby"));
var root = doc.Root;
```

Create and add elements with

```
var element = new XElement("Osoba",
    new XElement("Id", 1),
    new XElement("Imie", "Jan"),
    new XElement("Nazwisko", "Kowalski"),
    new XElement("Wiek", 23)
);
root.Add(element);
```

Finally save with

```
doc.Save(filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so one step by step solution would be to make a class Person that will hold name and lastname. Then in a loop first generate name and lastname randomly and check if there is already that combination in list therefore written in XML file already. If there is not, add that combination to list and call your write method. This way you will keep track of random combinations that are already written to XML because your list holds a copy. Person class is just a container that will help you more easily to check both fistname and lastname combination duplicates.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
    }

    private void createNode(string pID, string pName, string pSurname, string pAge, XmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("Osoba");
        writer.WriteStartElement("Id");
        writer.WriteString(pID);
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteStartElement("Imie");
        writer.WriteString(pName);
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteStartElement("Nazwisko");
        writer.WriteString(pSurname);
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteStartElement("Wiek");
        writer.WriteString(pAge);
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] Imie = { "Anna", "Piotr", "Katarzyna ", "Andrzej", "Małgorzata", "Jan", "Agnieszka ", "Stanisław", "Barbara", "Tomasz", "Marcin", "Marek", "Magdalena", "Łukasz" };
        string[] Nazwisko = { "Wieczorek", "Stępień", "Pawlak", "Baran", "Wróblewski", "Ostrowski", "Zając", "Adamczyk", "Walczak", "Michalak", "Jaworski" };
        Random losuj = new Random();
        List<Person> list = new List<Person>();

        XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("osoby.xml", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        writer.WriteStartDocument(true);
        writer.Indentation = 2;
        writer.WriteStartElement("Osoby");

        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        {
            var name = Imie[losuj.Next(0, 7)];
            var lastname = Nazwisko[losuj.Next(0, 7)];
            var presentInList = list.Where(p => p.Name == name && p.Lastname == lastname).FirstOrDefault();
            if (presentInList == null)
            {
                list.Add(new Person { Name = name, Lastname = lastname });
                createNode(i.ToString(), name, lastname, losuj.Next(1, 50).ToString(), writer);
            }
        }

        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndDocument();
        writer.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("Utworzono plik XML,teraz możesz zapisać plik XML do pliku TXT ! ");

    }
}
```

Comment: Form1.Person.Name ,Form1.Person.Lastname is inaccessible due to its protection level.How to fix it?

Comment: Sorry, my missight I forgot to make properties public. Edited.

Comment: Ok,works thx...but there is another problem:
The ‘!’ operator cannot be applied to operand of type  'Form1.Person'

Comment: Sorry again too much Javascript. Try now.

Comment: No problem :) These are my beginnings in c # and I make trivial mistakes myself.I do not know why but another error popped up after clicking the button:

System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  Message="Sequence contains no elements"

Comment: in this line : var presentInList = list.Where(p => p.Name == name && p.Lastname == lastname).First();

Comment: Yeah I edited too look again that line in post. LINQ has 2 versions of this operator the edited doent throw error if list is empty . Sorry once more :)

Comment: ok, the program is already running, but with the xml run, an inscription pops up :

"This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below."

and empty page

Do you know why?

Comment: That is a browser issue. Can be many things from installed extensions to other browser issues. Go to Incognito mode if you are using Chrome. See then if you have display. (CTRL+SHIFT+N)

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work on other browsers. Appears blank page with this message,as if there were no data saved at all...However, on the my old code, which is visible in the post, it shows me correctly,the inscription is the same.

Comment: I just opened it in Notepad and it's completely empty, there is no sign or nothing ...

The old code with my loop is working properly ...

Comment: See the latest edit. I think I haven't moved WriteEndElement out of loop. Try now.

Comment: only the inscription appeared -"<Osoby />"...Maybe I will share the whole code again here: https://pastebin.com/BnEXEGK3

Comment: Finally I think - condition was bad. I reproduced it and you can copy this edit.